# How does exactly this code work in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

For example this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo(int* x){ cout << "X = " << *x << endl;}

int main()
{
    int value = 5;
    int *p = &value;
    foo(p);
    foo(&value);
    return 0;
}
```

In the first call of function `foo` a copy of pointer p (x) is actually created within the function and deleted as soon as the function ends, right? In the second call of `foo` the address of variable value is taken and a pointer x is created with that address and is deleted as soon as the function ends, right? Which of these calls is cheaper in terms of stack memory consumption? Or are both the same thing?

Comment: They both end up doing the same thing in terms of semantics. I'd just stick with the second. If you're actually using C++, though, a reference might be more suitable.

Comment: Please don't tag C++ posts about pointers as "C" "reference"

Comment: lol I didn't expect a reply so fast. Thanks for the answer, well, so you mean the 2nd one is actually better? if it is then why?. Thanks in advance, and sry for taggin C also, Im new on this

Comment: In that simple case, it's likely the two generate the same code. In more complex cases it may not always, though.

Comment: @user1836252, It's the usual way to do it, and it saves a pointless line of code otherwise.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I was just curious about how that particular code work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both similar. The first looks more expensive because you're creating a pointer twice, once as a local variable (inside `main`) and again as a function parameter (passed to `foo`), however the "optimization" phase of the compiler will probably turn the first into the second (assuming that the only thing you do with `p` is pass it, and you don't reuse it later in `main`).

Comment: @user1836252 For that reason, a book might recommend that you write code to be as human-readable as possible, and let the compiler optimize the run-time. "Human-readable" is subjective: the example you gave is so simple that an extra variable doesn't help, but code like `current_balance = previous_balance + interest_paid; display(current_balance);` might be more readable than just `display(previous_balance + interest_paid);` because having a named (temporary) variable like `current_balance` helps to explain your intention to the person reading your code.

Answer (score 1):

They are almost identical. The only difference is that you have a pointer object `p` on the call stack in `main`, but if you're going to worry about that then you have issues. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first call, you are passing a variable containing the *address* of `value`.

In the second, you are passing the *address* of `value` directly.

Note that assignment operator says that both `p` and `&value` are the same, so you should be able to pass either one to the function as you have proven.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers have values that can be copied like everything else. They
have value-semantics.

```
void foo(int* t);
```

takes a pointer by value. It will create a copy of the pointer
argument and use it inside its body.

```
int value = 23;
int *p = &value; // &value takes the address of value and use it to copy initialize p
foo(p); // copy the value of the pointer inside foo
foo(&value); // do the same but don't create a temporary
```